# Google Sheets - return a specific value based on column of a specified cell in a sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I think this image describes this best.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9qUu.png)

I have a table where specific strings of text (they're actually URLs) are placed in columns. I have another tab where These text strings are in a single list, but I need to have a column next to it that finds which category they came from based on the the list/table on the left.

Is there a way to achieve this with a formula?

Thanks!

I tried Vlookup and other formulas but I'm not savvy enough to get what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try this formula in `Cell_K2` of your sample sheet (as in screenshot):*

```js
=map(L2:L,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(index(if(A2:J=Σ,A1:J1,)),1),"--"))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly and saved me a lot of time :)